# Device not Registered : Sending a log from an unregistered device is impossible error message on the device

Tags: codenameone

I have a Pro account but I still see this message:

> Device not Registered: Sending a log from an unregistered device is
>   impossible

...error message on the device

I remember this message due to calling the `sendLog()` when there is no internet connectivity on the device. I have the following questions:

1. Something like having to check `Log.getDeviceKey() != null` which will indicate if a device successfully registered and can send a log. Don't you think there should be a fallback mechanism to capture the events and send the log when there the connectivity is regained? Did this issue has been fixed yet. Please advise.
2. How do you register a device? What is the process to register a device from CN1?

Answer (score 0):

You implicitly register a device when you invoke `Log.getUniqueDeviceKey()`. It creates a unique device value which we use to identify the device. It needs an internet connection to work.

Comment: This is the fallback mechanism. If you explicitly try to send a log it tries to register the device and you get that if it fails.